# How to create and object doing a query with Entity

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity

I would like to obtain an object collection with 3 attributes but it is not possible because an error appears with text similar to this

> "Method 'First' can appear only in a final query."

My code is:

```
IEnumerable<InfEditModel> di = context.STRUCTURE.Where(x =>
    x.STRUCTURE_TIPO.STRUCTURE_CATEGORIA.CODIGO == "BA" &&
    CodProvincia.Contains(x.MUNICIPIO.PROVINCIA.CODIGO))
    .Select(x => new InfEditModel
    {
        PROVINCIA_NOMBRE = x.MUNICIPIO.PROVINCIA.NOMBRE,
        STRUCTURE_NOMBRE = x.NOMBRE,
        RECURSO_NOMBRE = x.RECURSO_STRUCTURE.First().RECURSO.NOMBRE
    }
);
```

Comment: what happens if you go like this: `x.RECURSO_STRUCTURE[0].RECORSO.NOMBRE` ?

Comment: The same if recurso.nombre.first is null.